# Get average (Quote field in BDH) when loading data from Bloomberg

Tags: matlab, bloomberg, blpapi

In Excel, it is possible to define whether the `BDH` function returns average (a) or close (c) quotes.

Can this be done when loading data from Bloomberg to MATLAB using the `history` command?

e.g., in MATLAB:

```
javaaddpath 'C\Matlab\blpapi3.jar'
c = blp;
h = history(c, 'SPX index', 'PX_LAST', '1/1/2015', today, 'monthly');
```

e.g., in Excel:

```
=BDH("SPX index","px_last",DATE(2015,1,1),TODAY(),"PER=M,quote=a","cols=2;rows=7")
=BDH("SPX index","px_last",DATE(2015,1,1),TODAY(),"PER=M,quote=C","cols=2;rows=7")
```